# SSRS keep showing error message: Testing On Load SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i'm getting a weird message in every computer / browser when accessing the Report Manager in SSRS.

the message shows up whenever the page is loading.
it's a pop-up box and has a yellow warning sign on it.
it says: "Message from webpage.Testing On Load SSRS."

what does it mean ?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like someone is testing some custom Javascript on the site.

Comment: i don't have much knowledg in java, more in SQL.. and our developer is away.. do you know how can i locate the problem? maybe fix it myself ?

Comment: You'll need remote access to the server.  Find the SSRS installation location, and check the "Pages" and "js" folder in both the ReportServer and ReportManager.  Look for any files recently modified.  Those are the most likely places someone who wants to add some javascript will do it.